# far parts invisible, though closer parts are alpha-transparent

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl

[image]

In the image above, the trees are drawn in a batch and I'm trying to draw the small tree in front of the bigger tree using its z position and regardless of the order they are added for drawing. I'm also using an orthographic projection.

Unfortunately, I'm using an unknown game engine where the devs are either inactive or just doesn't care that's why I'm hoping someone here can help but the gist is this:

```
start batch drawing
draw small tree at location: x, y, 1  // 1 to make it appear in front
draw big tree at location: x, y, 0
end batch drawing
```

In an OpenGL / glsl application, what are the things to do in general to make something like this work?

I've already tried the equivalent of

```
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: The trees are rectangular pictures, aren't they? Can you check whether they have an opaque  black background (as it seems) or have a transparent background (which I think you will need)? What format are the trees archived in (I guess pictures, or maybe 3d shapes)?

Comment: The trees have transparent background. If I add the small tree after the big tree for drawing, the result is correct. I don't know about your last question but I'm working on a workaround where I construct the rectangles myself, draw them in a batch and the GL flags I mentioned are enough to produce correct results.

Comment: Just found out that it's because of the shaders. I tweaked the fragment shader to discard it if the alpha is less than 0.5. I just expect it to that by default, because you know, working with sprites :/ and it also works just fine if I add the small tree first before the big tree.

Comment: In the text, you write that you draw a small tree in front of the big one, in the code, you draw the big tree behind the front one - this is the opposite order, but the order is important when blending, always draw back to front.

Comment: That's what this post is all about. I want the render order to be based on the z position regardless of the order I add them for drawing. Anyway, as per my previous comment, it's all solved now.

Comment: The image is unavailable, can you check the link again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you seem to be having is the difference between "drawn with non-opaque alpha values" and "actually being transparent".

OpenGL (and most other simple alpha-based rendering techniques) cannot do the kind of transparency where drawing behind an already drawn element makes part of the newly drawn element (partially) visible.
The color of any newly-drawn, non-opaque pixel is a mixture of its own color and the color already on that place. I.e. only two input values exist.
The mixture is controlled by the alpha value of the newly drawn pixel.
The color "already on that place" has lost information on involved colors and alpha values.

The problem visible in your picutre is caused by the fact that in addition to the alpha-controlled mixture there is also the z-controlled influence of other elements closer to the observer. Alpha values do not influence that mixture, the foremost elements simply wins. And this includes the partially, or even fully "transparent" parts of those closer elements, which have already been drawn (with or without allpha influence).

So the gist of this is, as mentioned in comments already,
with the simple alpha-rendering mechanisms, you have to sort rendering chronologically by distance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my second comment is not clear. I've already found the problem and it's solution.

Problem: the alpha is not discarded in the fragment shader

Solution:

```
if(gl_FragColor.a < 0.5)
        discard;
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but it's enough for pixel art sprites.

Thank you everyone for your time.

Comment: Discard can be relatively expensive. Unless you have a lot of sprites, it can often be more efficient to sort them on the CPU and guarantee that you render them back-to-front without needing discard in the shader.

If you have lots of large sprites with opaque areas you might want to consider something a little more advanced, like this: https://community.arm.com/graphics/b/blog/posts/mali-performance-7-accelerating-2d-rendering-using-opengl-es

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep this in mind in case of much needed optimization.